# Pivot с различными PivotItem

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте. Делаю расписание, и есть проблема: Как в существующий Pivot добавлять PivotItem, у когорого заголовок будет задаваться программно, контент PivotItem  которого составляет ListView, а у Listview идет привязка данных. То есть на выходе должны получится PivotItem'ы, название которых соответствует дням недели, а в каждом из них находится ListView с данными о расписании.

ListView:

```html
<ListView x:Key="SubjectsTable">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Weeks}" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonTime}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonType}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Auditory}" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstLastName}" Grid.Column="4" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

У `Pivot`, как и у любого списка есть свойство `ItemsSource`, в который можно скормить коллекцию дней недели.

Comment: А можно как-то чуть поподробнее. Просто напрямую с ItemsSource не работал и не разобрался.

Comment: Свойство `ItemsSource` предназначено для привязки коллекции в качестве источника данных.
Т.е. если у вас есть коллекция строк, то вы через `ItemsSource` можете привязать ее к `ListView`, например. Если используете `MVVM`, то выглядит так: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"/>`
То же самое  и с `Pivot` - создаете коллекцию с элементами `DateTime` и привязываете.

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже разобрался. Главное было просто не бояться экспериментировать.